# Unicode encoding behaving differently in two different IDE/Editors

Tags: python, character-encoding, visual-studio-code, pycharm, python-unicode

Environment Specs:

OS                : Windows 10

Python Interpreter: 3.7

PyCharm           : 2018.2.4 CE

VS Code           : 1.27.1

I use mostly VS Code when it comes to writing Python codes and occasionally PyCharm. Today I encountered an issue, I have a piece of code:

```
s = 'ياخشىمۇسىز'
b = bytes(s, encoding='utf-8')
print(b)
x = str(b, encoding='utf-8')
print(x)
```

If I run this one in VS Code I get the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4: character maps to <undefined>
```

but if I run the same code in PyCharm I get:

```
b'\xd9\x8a\xd8\xa7\xd8\xae\xd8\xb4\xd9\x89\xd9\x85\xdb\x87\xd8\xb3\xd9\x89\xd8\xb2'
ياخشىمۇسىز
```

So encoding works in one Editor and not in other, I didn't know that this is dependent on editor. Can anyone shed some light on this please?

Comment: Different Python versions?

Comment: its the shell ... pycharm runs in a shell that understands encodings better than the one that vscode runs ... pycharm does alot of things better than vs code imho ... but really thats just my experience

Comment: no, same PC, same interpreter(Python 3.7) , OS=win10

Comment: (that said im sure there is some way to configure vscode;s shell to work)

Comment: Do you get the same results with: `b = s.encode('utf8')` and then `s = b.decode('utf8')`